# Put the class containing the main method into a sub-package

Tags: java, package

I am making a project named TruckingCompany, there is a package name truckingCompany, and three sub-packages: utilities, means and objects.
Now I have put the class containing the main method into the utilities sub-package.
Is this correct? Should I put it into the truckingCompany package ( in no sub-package)?
So the generic question is: if there is a package, and some sub-package, and the main method uses classes from all sub-packages, is correct to put the class containing it in a sub-package?

PS: Let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: regarding Code Style or functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a baseline, from what I've seen so far a good practice is to put the class containing the main method at the top-level package.

In your case, I'd put your class under the package truckingCompany and not in a sub-package.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can just put it in `truckingCompany`. After all, it is your application's entry point.

Answer (score 1):

You should put in truckingCompany but it will work doesn't matter where ever you put it

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely irrelevant where you put your class. More specifically, a package has no special relation to its subpackages. The packages are basically a flat namespace of package names. I would also like to add that there are some conventions to be followed with package names:

1. You are supposed to use all lowercase letters;
2. the package name should be derived from an internet domain name that you own: com.truckingcompany.stuff.morestuff.